# How to Download all Podio Item IDs at once

Tags: podio

I was wondering if there is a way to download all item IDs within Podio at once so I can upload this information into Zapier. Otherwise I would have to go into every single contact that I have (almost 2000) and then input it into an excel spreadsheet so I can upload it to Zapier. Please let me know if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can enable unique app id (Wrench icon -> App settings -> Advanced ->
   Show unique ID)
2. Then use excel export ( this will give an
   excel file with all items with unique ids, which is `app_item_id`
   but not `item_id`)
3. Then you can use `get_by_app_item_id` method  https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-by-app-item-id-66506688 method to get all items

Sorry, but I don't know if Zapier can work with `app_item_id`